# Как вывести значение отсортированного массива?

Tags: php, массивы

После сортировки многомерного массива

```
$brands = Array (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 32
                    [brand] => Samsung
                )
        
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 33
                    [brand] => LG
                )
)
```

про значению ключа с помощью `array_filter`

```
$arr = array_filter($brandId_page, function($ar) {
        return ($ar['brand'] == 'Samsung');
});
```

Получаю массив в массиве:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 32
            [brand] => Samsung
        )

)
```

Как грамотно получить значение id из последней конструкции?

Comment: там всегда один элемент?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если элемент всегда один, то достаточно просто взять его из результата:

```
echo array_pop($array)['id'];
```

либо

```
echo end($array)['id'];
```

---

Список всех `id` можно получить так:

```
print_r(array_column($array, 'id'));
```

---

```
$arr = [
    1 => [
            'id' => 32,
            'brand' => 'Samsung'
        ]

];

// array_pop($arr)['id']; 
// 32        

// end($arr)['id'];
// 32    

// print_r(array_column($arr, 'id'));
// Array
//    (
//        [0] => 32
//    )
```